# React proxy to express backend not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

My problem is that I have a create-react-app setup in a client folder and I need to connect it to a backend which I am using express for. The express server is running on localhost:3001, so in the client's package.json I have `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`.

*client/package.json:*

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
    ...
}
```

And when I try making a simple fetch to the server, I get CORS blocked, despite the server acknowledging that the request was hit.

*server/index.ts:*

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Received");
    res.send("Received");
});
```

Note that the server console logs "Received"

*client/App.tsx:*

```
async function onclick () {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api')
        .then((x: Response) => {
            console.log(x);
        })
        .catch((e: Error) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
}
```

The console log shows e was 'TypeError: failed to fetch'

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I have checked other threads and tried their solution of deleting package-lock and node_modules many times now but with no luck.

Comment: if you are using proxy then you don't need to add complete path in `fetch` method, try this `fetch('/api')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're fetching `http://localhost:3001/api` you're trying to fetch the data **directly** from your node server. The request is cosidered `CORS` as the ports of the request origin and request destination are different: `3000 != 3001`. While the [proxy server](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) works on the same domain and port your `create-react-app` is served from (`http://localhost:3000` in your case).

Change the request url to make requests to the proxy itself and you're good:

```js
  ...
await fetch('/api')
  ...
```

Or include and config [cors express middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) to allow requests from `localhost:3000` or other trusted origins as a more advanced solution.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. It makes sense what you're saying about fetching directly from localhost, this would definitely make switching to a production environment much easier without the need to replace the fetch path.